# How to make Image control in WPF to support both Left Click and Drag operations?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, draggable

I need to display a floating image in WPF and it needs to support the following operations

1. The user should be able to click the image (like a toggle button).
2. The user should be able to drag the image anywhere on the screen.

I am using PreviewMouseDown event on the window to handle the drag and created InputBindings for Left Click on the Image control to handle the click event on the Image.

The Click command handler is not getting called.

Below is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Views.ImageControlTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="130" Width="224"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown">

    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.0" Color="White"/>
    </Window.Background>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="108"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Cursor="Hand" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="108" Width="108">
                <Image.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ClickCommand, Mode=OneTime}" />
                </Image.InputBindings>
            </Image>
       
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray"  Text={Binding State} FontSize="14" Height="20" Width="224" FontFamily="Segoe UI"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
        
</Window>
```

Comment: just put the image in a button and make the button do the magic

Comment: Tried using a Button. It does not seem to work .                                                  
                                                                                                                             
 <Button  Command="{Binding BadgeClickCommand}">
            <Image Cursor="Hand" Source="{Binding DisplayedImagePath}" Stretch="None"/>
  </Button>

Answer (score 1):

`InputBinding` is a highler level API that relies on core WPF mouse and keyboard events. Thus, if you handle the bubbling `PreviewMouseDown` on the `Window`, its `LeftMouseButtonDown` counterpart will not get raised by the original source (the `Image`) and there will be no event to trigger the gesture. Consider another approach that will not require handiling the preview event.